# Jasmine how to test a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've just started testing with the Jasmine-Karma framework and was slightly confused. I'm trying to test a file called native.js. I've written my test and I'm clueless as to what is causing the test to fail.

Here's my native.js file

```
    var goBack = function() {
    window.history.back();
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide()
    return "now";
}

Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
};

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
};
```

Here's my unit for testing the onDeviceReady() function: 
native.test.js:

```
describe("native.js", function() {
  var onDeviceReady = new onDeviceReady();

  it("return 2 when device is ready", function() {
  expect(OnDeviceReady()).toEqual("now");
  });

});
```

Comment: What is the error message from karma? Can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: OnDeviceReady is not function. Try `expect(OnDeviceReady).toEqual("now");`

Comment: @NathanWilson I get the error that "TypeError: undefined is not a function" at the first line of my native.test.js

Comment: @jedrzejchalubek Sorry for my error. First I tried OnDeviceReady(),and then added it as a variable and then tried it as OnDeviceReady.

Comment: So it's saying `describe()` is not a function. That sounds like a config problem. Do you have the `karma-jasmine` dependency in `package.json`, and `frameworks: ['jasmine']` in `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: You also have capitalized `OnDeviceReady` in your test, which is not defined anywhere I can see.